# NIC Remains Active After shutdown

Tags: shutdown, network-adapter, links

Windows 8.1 during shutdown the ethernet adapter light goes out but comes back on after a second. Power is off but the adapter light is on and there is link activity. This does not happen in sleep mode or in hybernate. Anybody have a clue?

Comment: That's quite normal, is your device configured for wake-on-lan?

Comment: Typically you can set up in BIOS whether to allow wake-up on LAN. If not needed, it's advisable to disable it, as the NIC probably still consumes significant power.

Answer (score 0):

Your network card is still drawing a tiny amount of power. For [wake-on-lan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) your network card needs to have power for this process to work. You can unplug the computer from the wall and you should see the network light go off. This is perfectly normal.